# How can I give permission to authenticated users to edit the content type 'ABC'?

Tags: 7, users

we have view and edit tab for any content

How can I have such a view and edit tab for authenticated user ?
I have given the following permissions to content of type 'ABC'
- Create own content
- Create new content 
- Edit own content
- Edit any content 
- Delete own content
- Delete any content 
- View published content
But still the authenticated user cannot edit the content of type 'ABC'?
How can I achieve it?

When I try to access node/205/edit page as an authenticated user

I get the access denied message

DNA image 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module, especially it's Node Acces tool:

> Devel Node Access (DNA)
>
> View the node access entries for the node(s) that are shown on a page. Essential for developers of node access modules and useful for site admins in debugging problems with those modules.

It will tell you exactly what permission is missing.

To debug for particular existing user, consider adding [Masquerade](https://drupal.org/project/masquerade) to the mix:

> The masquerade module is designed as a tool for site designers and site administrators. It allows a user with the right permissions to switch users.

That way you will be able to see DNA report just as the exact user who encountered problem.

What you should see is 2 lists:

[image: List 1]

[image: List 2]

**If these look about right**

Go to *Home ⏩ Administration ⏩ Configuration ⏩ Content authoring* and make sure your user has the proper text format permissions:

[image: text formats]